# Cannot Resolve Symbol touch for TapOptions in Appium

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I am trying to use `TapOption` in Appium. But I am not able to resolve dependencies for `TapOption`. Getting error `"can not resolve symbol touch"`.

I am using Java 1.8 & using IntelliJ and have tried it like this:

```
DeviceCapability deviceCapability = new DeviceCapability();
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = deviceCapability.LaunchDeviceCapability();
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
```

Comment: Improved Java code indentation, highlighted Java code within text blocks and slightly reworded some sentences.

Answer (score 0):

There is no symbol "touch", copy paste full part of the code and error.
Plus make sure that you have correct import of `import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;`

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure to use the latest version of the [Appium Java Client Driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.2.0) which is `io.appium:java-client:7.2.0` as of now.

I would recommend using a dependency management solution like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org) because Appium has some [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)

[image]

and is guaranteed to work only with the given versions of the given libraries. You can check out [Appium - Code Examples - Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java) for example project setup which you can use as the reference or basis.

You may also find [How to use touch action in new java client 6.0.0-BETA4](https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-use-touch-action-in-new-java-client-6-0-0-beta4/21336) discussion thread useful, there are some code examples for different touch actions there

Comment: Thanks. I was using the old version of Appium. After updating the maven version the error get resolved